# uisearchbar uisearchdisplaycontroller tableview subtitle error

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, searchbar, searchdisplaycontroller

I have a little problem with my searchbar for a tableview

I have made a tableview with an array tableViewArray.
The tableViewArray consists of many rows of another array consisting of [text, distance].
Everything is working fine.
Now i added a searchBar and a searchdisplaycontroller, that searched based on a new array of string (from the "text" object of the tableViewArray).
I thought the search should only be available for the text, and the search method is implemented on that.

Now when i get the search result, it looks good, and the search returns expected rows. The problem is with the search tableViews subtitle. It is showing the distances for row 1, 2, 3 for the tableViewArray.

I need it to map the distance to the text shown in the search tableview rows.
I imagine i need to make a new table view array for the search results consisting of [text distance]. the text is not a problem since it is from the search result, but how do i map the new distance to the old distance???

The search method im using in the search delegate is :

```
searchResults = [[NSArray alloc]init];
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                            searchText];
searchResults = [searchItems  filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
```

Hope somebody can help :) Thanks in advance!

The original code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if (theTableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [searchResults count];
    } else {
        return [tableViewArray count];
    }
}  

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:     UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                  reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier] ;

     if (theTableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {

    } else {
         cell = [theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier     forIndexPath:indexPath];
}

    // Configure the cell...
    // cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
   // cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

    if (theTableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.text = [[[tableViewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]     objectAtIndex:0] subtitle];
}

    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];




float blabla=  [[[tableViewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex: 1] doubleValue];
if (blabla < 1000) {
         cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f m",blabla];
} else {
         cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f km",blabla/1000];
}





NSString *text = [[[tableViewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0] subtitle];
NSRange q8RangeValue = [text rangeOfString:@"Q8" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
NSRange okRangeValue = [text rangeOfString:@"OK" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

if (q8RangeValue.length >0  ) {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"q8.png"];
} else if (okRangeValue.length >0 ) {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"OK logo.png"];

} else {
        cell.imageView.image = nil;
}

return cell;
}
```

And where i make the array for the search:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation Location calculator distance array for the tableView");

NSMutableArray * distancesInReverseOrder = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];



for (int i = 0; i<allAnnotations.count; i++) {

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0] ;
CLLocationCoordinate2D annotationCoord = [[allAnnotations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] coordinate];


CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:annotationCoord.latitude  longitude:annotationCoord.longitude];

distanceToMe = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:location];

[distancesInReverseOrder insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: distanceToMe] atIndex:0];

}


distances = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[distancesInReverseOrder reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects]];

// Assuming you have your points on the map in an NSArray called
// allAnnotations and your distances in distances, create a
// new mutable array to hold both
tableViewArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Iterate over all of the points, and add a new element to the mutable
// array which is a new array containing a point and its distance
for (int i = 0; i < allAnnotations.count; i++) {
    NSArray *newItem = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [allAnnotations objectAtIndex: i], [distances objectAtIndex: i], nil];
    [tableViewArray addObject: newItem];
}

// Now, sort the new array based upon the distance in the second element
// of each array (ie, the distance).
[tableViewArray sortUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSNumber *dist1 = [obj1 objectAtIndex:1];
    NSNumber *dist2 = [obj2 objectAtIndex:1];

    return [dist1 compare:dist2];
}];

searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[tableViewArray count]];




searchItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < allAnnotations.count; i++) {
    NSArray *newItem = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [[[tableViewArray objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:0] subtitle], @"bla", nil];
    [searchItems addObject: newItem];
}

/*
for (int i=0; i<tableViewArray.count; i++) {
    [searchItems insertObject:[[[tableViewArray objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:0] subtitle] atIndex:0];
}
*/

NSLog(@"searchitems count is %i", searchItems.count);

[tableView reloadData];

[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

}

```
    - (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
 /*
// Update the filtered array based on the search text and scope.
// Remove all objects from the filtered search array
[searchResults removeAllObjects];
// Filter the array using NSPredicate
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains[c] %@",searchText];
```

//  searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[tableViewArray objectAtIndex:1]  filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];

*/

```
/*
```

searchResults = [[NSArray alloc]init];

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                searchText];

    searchResults =[searchItems filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];


*/

// Create index set of all objects in textArray that contain searchText:
NSIndexSet *set = [searchItems indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:
                   ^BOOL(NSString *text, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                       NSRange range = [text rangeOfString:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch)];
                       return (range.location != NSNotFound);
                   }];

// Filter textArray:
filteredTextArray = [searchItems objectsAtIndexes:set];
// Filter distanceArray:
filteredDistanceArray = [distances objectsAtIndexes:set];

NSLog(@"filtered text array is %@", filteredTextArray);
NSLog(@"filtered distance array is %@",filteredDistanceArray);
```

Comment: did u copy the objects in your searchresults array to ur tableview array??

Comment: How can i do that? the searchResults array is solely made of index 0 of the tableview array. so it does not take the index 1 (the distance) into consideration at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you have 2 separate arrays that are used as data source for the table view, let's call them `textArray` and `distanceArray`.

Now you filter the `textArray` according to the search string and you need the "corresponding" filtering of `distanceArray`.

One way to do this is to replace `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` with `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest`, because that returns a set of matching indices that can be applied to both arrays:

```
// Create index set of all objects in textArray that contain searchText:
NSIndexSet *set = [textArray indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:
    ^BOOL(NSString *text, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSRange range = [text rangeOfString:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch)];
        return (range.location != NSNotFound);
    }];

// Filter textArray:
filteredTextArray = [textArray objectsAtIndexes:set];
// Filter distanceArray:
filteredDistanceArray = [distanceArray objectsAtIndexes:set];
```

Now you can use `filteredTextArray` and `filteredDistanceArray` as data source for the search table view.

**Alternatively**, you could use a single array as data source if each object in the array is for example a dictionary containing both text and distance for one row.

**UPDATE:** As I understand it now, each item of your `tableViewArray` is an array with 2 items (one for the text and one for the distance).

In this case I would recommend to filter the `tableViewArray` directly:

```
NSIndexSet *set = [tableViewArray indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:
                   ^BOOL(NSArray *item, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                       NSString *subtitle = [[item objectAtIndex:0] subtitle];
                       NSRange range = [subtitle rangeOfString:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch)];
                       return (range.location != NSNotFound);
                   }];

searchResults = [tableViewArray objectsAtIndexes:set];
```

Now `searchResults` is the filtered array, and each item has the same structure as the items in `tableViewArray`.

This simplifies things in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, e.g.

```
if (theTableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [[[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0] subtitle];
     distance = [[[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex: 1] doubleValue];
} else {
    cell.textLabel.text = [[[tableViewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0] subtitle];
    distance = [[[tableViewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex: 1] doubleValue];
}
```

Comment: Hello, well i use the same array for the datasource of the tableview. But this array is a combination of two arrays as you mention. index 0 of tableview array comes from a locationArray and index 1 comes from a distance array. i basically make my search on the location array which in this case is "searchitems" (copy of the locaion array). So the tableViewArray is (index 0 location, index 1 distance).  

In the code you wrote, where do you define what the actual search is done on? (i will meanwhile try your solution i think that is almost what i thought must be the answer)
by the way, THANKS :)

Comment: @B-Man: My code searches `searchText` in the array `textArray`. - I do not yet understand how your arrays work. It would perhaps help if you show your code of `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. - Or you try my solution first and reply if you have more questions ... just as you want.

Comment: @B-Man: Please see my updated answer, I hope that it helps. Otherwise you are welcome to ask again, but I will probably not reply before tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks man that looks amazing. i will look into it and get back to you tomorrow also :) Have a good night :)